# Classes and Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm working on a class that will  take an employee id and pay in and then display it.
The problem that comes up is it doesn't flag any errors, but it completely skips past code where i'm supposed to input the data.

This is what my code looks like.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

class employee
{
private:
    int id;
    float compensation;
public:
    employee() : id(0), compensation(0)
    {}
    employee(int num, float pay) : id(num), compensation(pay)
    {}
    void setid(int i) { id=i; }
    void setcomp(float comp) { compensation=comp; }
    void displayinfo() { cout << "Id: " << id << endl << "Pay: " << compensation << endl; }
};

int main ( int argc, char* argv)
{
employee i1(1111, 8.25);
i1.displayinfo();

employee i2[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter Employee ID: ";
    cin >> i2[i].setid(num);
    cout << "Enter Employee Pay: ";
    cin >> i2[i].setcomp(num);
}

for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    i2[i].displayinfo();
}


//------------------------------------------------
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? `cin >> i2[i].setid(num);` shouldn't compile at all, for multiple reasons.

Comment: Yeah the codes verbatim for what I have in my compiler and it does compile. Output is Id: 1111 \n Pay: 8.25 \n Press Any Key to Continue...

Comment: Well it turns out my compiler was being funky, still no idea why. I cleaned the Project, and Rebuilt numerous times. It wasn't until I copy pasted the entire code into a completely new project that the errors popped. Not too impressed with VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

This code shouldn't even compile. The problem is your loop:

```
employee i2[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter Employee ID: ";
    cin >> i2[i].setid(num);             // Reading into a void return value.
    cout << "Enter Employee Pay: ";
    cin >> i2[i].setcomp(num);             // Reading into a void return value.
}
```

You'd need to, at a minimum, change this to:

```
employee i2[3];
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    int num; float pay;
    cout << "Enter Employee ID: ";
    cin >> num;
    i2[i].setid(num);
    cout << "Enter Employee Pay: ";
    cin >> pay;
    i2[i].setcomp(pay);
}
```

Note: your sample code does *not* compile:

> c:\users\nate\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\employeetest\employeetest\employeetest.cpp(33): error C2065: 'num' : undeclared identifier
>   1>c:\users\nate\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\employeetest\employeetest\employeetest.cpp(35): error C2065: 'num' : undeclared identifier

With lines 33 & 35 being the lines I indicated in the first code block.

**Edit:**
After making the indicated change, I get this output:

```
Id: 1111
Pay: 8.25
Enter Employee ID: 1
Enter Employee Pay: 1234.5
Enter Employee ID: 3
Enter Employee Pay: 5678.9
Enter Employee ID: 4
Enter Employee Pay: 123
Id: 1
Pay: 1234.5
Id: 3
Pay: 5678.9
Id: 4
Pay: 123
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Also, avoid the `system` function. You can accomplish the same without spawning another process (`system` results in a separate process being created) by doing:
    cout << "Press [ENTER] to continue..." << endl;
    cin.get();

Comment: Thanks, it turns out there was something funky going on with my compiler. Visual Studio 2008 kept compiling with no errors. I cleaned my old project and rebuilt but was getting the same results. It wasn't until I  copied the entire code to a new project that the errors showed up.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know system spawns another process. I'll do cin.get instead from now on.

Comment: cin.get() won't do what you want either, because there will be a newline in the buffer which cin.get() will read and then return immediately.  This is closer: `#include <iostream> #include <limits> void pause(char const* prompt="Press ENTER to continue.") { using namespace std; if (prompt) cout << prompt; cin.clear(); for (char c; cin.readsome(&c, 1);) {} cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); }`

Comment: However, a better solution is to *not* include this in your program. Either run your program from the command line or from a wrapper (such as a .bat file; get your IDE to do this) which runs your program then runs the system "pause" command.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> i2[i].setid(num);
```

You are compiling different code than you show.  This code will give a [compile error](http://ideone.com/HEMn4), because setid returns void and num has not been declared.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and its compiling fine but skipping over everything in the for loops. It displays i1 but completely skips past the other relevant code.

Comment: @Lorek: Either that compiler is broken or something is not as you describe.  There are compiler bugs, but my bet is you overlooked something. ;)

Comment: Weird, I copied the entire code to a new project and rebuilt and the compiler errors showed up.